# Python 3 class inheritance with parameters

Tags: inheritance, python-3.x, parameters, attributes, subclass

So I have a class, character(), and a subclass,  npc(character). They look like this:

```
class character():
    def __init__(self,name,desc):
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.attr = ""    
        #large list of attributes not defined by parameters
```

and

```
class npc(character):
    def __init__(self,greetings,topics):
        self.greetings = greetings
        self.topics = topics
        character.__init__(self)
        self.pockets = []
        #more attributes specific to the npc subclass not defined by parameters
```

however, when I call an attribute from 'Character' that should exist (or so I think) in 'Npc', like 'name' or 'desc' or 'attr', I get a "does not exist/is undefined" error. Am I just not doing inheritance right? What's going on here? Am I mixing up attributes and parameters?

Answer (score 25):

the constructor of you class character is :

```
class character():
    def __init__(self, name, desc):
```

so you have to precise name and desc when you make npc herited.
As I personnaly prefer super this would be:

```
class npc(character):
    def __init__(self,greetings,topics):
        super().__init__("a_name", "a_desc")
        self.greetings = greetings
        self.topics = topics
        self.pockets = []
        #more attributes specific to the npc subclass not defined by parameters
```

Comment: @Metalgearmaycry - Don't forget to upvote and accept answers by clicking the up arrow and green-faded tick on the left-hand side. This let's everyone know your problem has been solved :)

Comment: i know this comment is rather late, but is there a way to not  call the super().__init__ method with those specific parameters but to make them a variable i can specify while creating an object of that class? something like:'
x = npc("a_greeting","a_topic","a_name","a_desc") ?

Comment: @James You can make them same argument in `npc.__init__(self, greet, topic, name, desc)` and call `super().__init__(name, desc)`. Or using `**kwargs` and pass them using key word unpack will be more flexible and easy to write.