# Python inner classes

Tags: python

I want to create an object car using inner classes, this object car have attributes like number of seats, color, year, engine. The last attribute engine capacity will have another attributes like number of valves, type of fuel, kms by lts.

so I am creating a class car first and then engine class:

```
class car:
     def __init__(self, color, year, engine):
        self.color = color
        self.year = year
        self.engine = engine

class engine:
    def __init__(lts, kms_by_lts, fuel_type, valves ):
        self.lts = lts
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.valves = valves
        self.kms_by_lts = kms_by_lts
```

---

```
>> my_car = car('blue','2010','v6')
>>> my_car.engine
'v6'
```

I want to access a class inside another class like as follow:

```
>>> my_car.v6.lts = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: car instance has no attribute 'v6'
```

Could help me with this issue.

Regards

I recreate the object as follow:

```
class car:
     def __init__(self, color, year, engine):
        self.color = color
        self.year = year
        self.engine = engine()

class engine:
    def __init__(lts, kms_by_lts, fuel_type, valves ):
        self.lts = lts
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.valves = valves
        self.kms_by_lts = kms_by_lts
```

Having the following error

```
>>> my_car = car('blue','2010','v6')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: The attribute `engine` has value `v6`. Why do you want to refer to the attribute by a different name?

Comment: >>> my_car.engine.lts = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lts'

Comment: That’s the vale you gave it. You need to create an engine object if you want it to have attribute ‘lts’

Comment: Hi peter, the idea access the attribute using their name "engine" as following
>>> my_car.engine.lts = 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lts'

Comment: But you’re setting engine to be a string not an engine object

Comment: could you please give an example, if I change the variable engine to call the function engine() I have the following error

>>> class car:
...      def __init__(self, color, year, engine):
...         self.color = color
...         self.year = year
...         self.engine = engine()
.

Comment: >>> class engine:
...     def __init__(lts, kms_by_lts, fuel_type, valves ):
...         self.lts = lts
...         self.fuel = fuel
...         self.valves = valves
...         self.kms_by_lts = kms_by_lts
...
>>> my_car = car('blue','2010','v6')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
TypeError: 'str' object is not callabl

Comment: You are pretty much trying/wanting to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20668910/python-3-class-inheritance-with-parameters). Inheritance is a good approach here. I suggest reading that and branching out to other topics on classes, inheritance and how to use classes inside classes.

Comment: `self.engine = engine()` does not help you here. In your case the `engine` that is being used is in fact the *string* "v6" that you passed. Read the link I posted in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct an engine first, then a [car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodge_Viper):

```
my_engine = engine(8.4, 5.5, 'petrol', 20)
my_car = car('blue', '2010', my_engine)
```

Now you can access `my_car.engine.lts`, for example.

Comment: Would be good to note that for this to work, they should not be using the latest version of their code, but rather the original version. The latest version is doing `self.engine = engine()`

Comment: @idjaw: Nice note, indeed I wrote this against the first chunk of code in the question, not the chunk lower down.

Comment: Thanks idjaw, its working now, and thanks again for the suggestion.
Thanks Peter for your cooperation.